# Performance Improvement went wrong in Production, worked fine in Test

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

We have an application supported by vendor and there was a piece of code which was doing very heavy logical reads and time consuming inside a procedure, hence I proposed them to tweak the query a bit to have much lesser IO and time, it worked well in test in terms of data and performance however its failing in production and returning different data, we had to rollback the changes. Need your expert advise on this.

This was tested for data in Test environment for more than 3 months and we never had any data issue. Started failing sparingly in Production immediately after the deployment and was producing inconsistent data.

Existing Query:

```
SELECT @Ref= CAST(MAX(ISNULL(CAST(ref_clnt AS INT),0))+1 AS VARCHAR(10)) 
FROM table_name WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE s_mode='value'
```

Proposed Query:

```
SELECT @Ref = ref_clnt+1 FROM table_name WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE RefNo = (SELECT MAX(RefNo) FROM table_name WHERE s_mode = 'value')
```

The DDL of table is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_name](
    [RefNo] [dbo].[udt_RefNo] NOT NULL,
    [S_Mode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ref_clnt] [varchar](50) NULL)
CONSTRAINT [PK_table_name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RefNo] ASC
)
```

Providing only those columns from definition which is used in the query.

`Udt_RefNo` is a user defined datatype as:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_RefNo] FROM [char](16) NOT NULL
GO
```

Version of SQL Server: *Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3) Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit)*.

Non-clustered index covering columns as shown below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ncidx_table_name_1] ON [dbo].[table_name]
(
    [S_Mode] ASC,
    [S_Status] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ref_clnt])
```

Please find the query plans as requested:

- [Previous Query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJomAX-dN)
- [Proposed Query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1SkJE-_V)

[image: Execution Plan]
Comparison of Number of Reads after enabling statistics IO and time:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row affected)
Table 'table_name'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2732, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 157 ms,  elapsed time = 161 ms.

(1 row affected)
Table 'table_name'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Vendor has come back with suggestion as

```
SELECT MAX(ISNULL(ref_clnt,0))+1 FROM table_name WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE S_Mode='value'
```

Issue is - how to test them as all of them seems to work for most of the scenario however fails only in few cases. I am not very much aware of the application and its vendor supported one, so can't get much details like how does business logic work for underlying procedure.

Comment: Comments [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91387/discussion-on-question-by-learning-dbadmin-performance-improvement-went-wrong-in). Please remember to write answers as answers, and add clarifications to the question body. - See https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment for guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your rewrite does not have the same semantics as the original query, so different results are not surprising.

This is true without worrying about the `NOLOCK` hint, and even if it is (somehow) guaranteed that the highest `ref_clnt` value is associated with the row having the highest `RefNo` value. See [this db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=672e9667629ea4bb739e58d4652d6fac).

Precision is important when dealing with computers, so you need to think carefully about data types and edge cases. The maximum `RefNo` calculation will use **string sorting semantics**, so '999' sorts higher than '1000'. There are several other important differences between the queries. I'm not going to list all of them, but `NULL` handling is [another example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16a04f4248a511e0788c9cdbf135632f).

There are also numerous bugs in both versions of the code. The original will fail if any `ref_clnt` value of -1000000000 or lower is returned, because that will not fit in `varchar(10)`. The sign makes the length 11.

The easiest way to *safely* improve the original version of the code is to add an index on a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name 
ADD ref_cc AS 
    ISNULL(CAST(ref_clnt AS integer), 0);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX i 
ON dbo.table_name (S_Mode, ref_cc);
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0858599d3a606bde38748f03880e331)

The execution plan can then seek directly to the highest `ref_clnt` row (sorted as integer) for the given `S_Mode` value:

[image: execution plan]

The vendor's original SQL may still be of debatable quality, but at least it will run faster and produce the same results.

---

The vendor's new suggestion:

```
SELECT MAX(ISNULL(ref_clnt,0))+1 FROM table_name WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE S_Mode='value'
```

...is still problematic, at least in theory, because [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) uses the data type of the first parameter, so the integer literal `0` is implicitly cast to `varchar(50)`.

> The value of *check_expression* is returned if it is not NULL; otherwise, *replacement_value* is returned after it is implicitly converted to the type of *check_expression*, if the types are different. *replacement_value* can be truncated if *replacement_value* is longer than *check_expression*.

The `MAX` still operates on a string, which may produce [unexpected results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=711d58722df238451a2acd2c19cb7a1d). In any case the expression is still not seekable without a (different) computed column index.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that `@Ref` is `varchar(10)`. `Ref_clnt` is `varchar(50)` and you are adding one to it.

```
SELECT @Ref = ref_clnt+1
```

...will generate an implicit conversion.

I have had this issue show up in execution plans as a warning and it impacted performance in our application. Most of the cases I have seen were when the coalesce statement was used like this:

```
coalesce(field_name, 0) = 0
```

when it should have been:

```
coalesce(field_name, '0') = '0' or coalesce(field_name, '') = ''
```

...because `field_name` was `varchar`.

Comment: Cool, take a look at this Q&A: [What Triggers This Warning: Type Conversion in Expression May Affect “CardinalityEstimate” in Query Plan Choice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231948/what-triggers-this-warning-type-conversion-in-expression-may-affect-cardinalit).